# How to fetch value from column in another pandas dataframe by id

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have one pandas dataframe `df1` contains `id` and `name` columns, and another dataframe `df2` contains only `id` column, how can we fetch name with id in `df2` from `df1` without writing loops?

[image: target result]

Sample code is attached as follows, thanks!

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

def add_name_by_id():
    df1 = pd.DataFrame(np.array([[1, 'jack'], [2, 'marry'], [3, 'tom'], [4, 'helen']]),
                       columns=['id', 'name'])
    print(df1)
    df2 = pd.DataFrame(np.array([[1, 4, 20], [2, 2, 30], [2, 3, 30], [3, 3, 25], [
                       3, 2, 25], [4, 4, 35]]), columns=['id', 'hours', 'price'])
    print(df2)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    add_name_by_id()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, I have `Reproduced` `DataFrames (df1) and (df2)` mentioned in your **query**. So, `Code` for `DataFrame` `Reproduction` as stated below:-

```
# Import all the Important Libraries
import pandas as pd 

# Reproducing 'DataFrame 1 (df1)'
df1 = pd.DataFrame({
    'id': [1, 2, 3, 4],
    'name': ['jack', 'marry', 'tom', 'helen']
})

# Reproducing 'DataFrame 2 (df2)'
df2 = pd.DataFrame({
    'id': [1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4],
    'hours': [4, 2, 3, 3, 2, 4],
    'price': [20, 30, 30, 25, 25, 35]
})

# Print Records of 'df1'
df1
```

```
# Output of above cell:-
    id  name
0   1   jack
1   2   marry
2   3   tom
3   4   helen
```

```
# Print Records of 'df2'
df2
```

```
# Output of above cell:-
    id  hours   price
0   1   4       20
1   2   2       30
2   2   3       30
3   3   3       25
4   3   2       25
5   4   4       35
```

---

So, now we have `reproduced` our `DataFrames` and we can move towards our `Solution Part`. If you `Analyze` your `Target Result` then it was nothing but a `Merged dataFrame` of `df1` and `df2` based on their `id`. We can divide our `Tasks` as:-

- `Primary Task`:- To `merge` both `DataFrame` on `id`
- `Secondary Task`:- To `Calculate` `Amount` based on `Merged dataFrame` **OR** `Target Result` values. `Amount` is nothing but `hours * price`.

So, `Code` for both Scenario was given below:-

```
# Merge both 'DataFrames' for Target Result
target_result = pd.merge(left=df1, right=df2, on='id')

# Calculate 'Amount' for 'Target Result'
target_result['amount'] = target_result['hours']*target_result['price']

# Print 'Target Result'
target_result
```

```
# Output of above cell:-
    id  name    hours   price   amount
0   1   jack    4       20      80
1   2   marry   2       30      60
2   2   marry   3       30      90
3   3   tom     3       25      75
4   3   tom     2       25      50
5   4   helen   4       35      140
```

> To Learn more about `pandas.merge()`:- [Click Here !!!](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.merge.html)

As you can see we have achieved our `Desired Output`. Hope this `Solution` helps you.

Comment: Thanks for detailed input. One minor questions, why id column in df1 is taken as object type, but does not happen for df2, thus need one more step conversion: df1['id'] = df1['id'].astype(int)

Comment: Sorry, I forget about that part, and Thanks for the valuable feedback & Suggestion for `Update` in the current `Solution`.

Answer (score 1):

```
df = pd.merge(left=df1, right=df2, how='inner', on='id')
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `pandas.DataFrame.merge`

```py
df2 = df2.merge(df1, on=['id'])
```